# Why is "What color eyes does she have?" correct? Shouldn't it be "What eye color does she have?"?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled upon this expression in a video and thought it was wrong, but googling it I found that it is actually correct. It feels wrong to my non-native ears to hear "color eyes" instead of "eye color", and I wonder if you guys think this is natural.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that your first version is far more idiomatic.

Comment: What size shoes does she wear?  What age children does she have?

Comment: @HotLicks It probably comes from "What color of eyes..." becoming "What color o' eyes..." in speech and eventually the *of* drops off completely becoming *What color eyes..."

Comment: @psosuna - I doubt it.  Likely the same constructions are found in English's source languages.

Comment: @HotLicks It’s certainly found in the Scandiwegian languages. A quick Googling seems to indicate that it’s not used in German, but my German isn’t very good, so I may just be searching for strings that result in the wrong expressions coming up.

Comment: Can *What size shoes do you wear?* occur in the Scandy tongues?

Comment: The same construction is used in Dutch, e.g. *welke kleur ogen heb jij?*. It may indeed be a very old case of ellipsis of the 'possessive' praeposition.